# Minecraft java: How to summon a custom splash potion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So the problem I am currently having is that I do not know the nbt to summon a custom splash potion in MCJE 1.16. I tried `/summon splash_potion`. This only summoned a uncraftable splash potion. I was wondering if anyone knew the nbt to get the splash potion to have swiftness,healing,etc on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summon potion ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:swiftness"}}}
```

This will summon a splash potion of swiftness, and gives the swiftness effect.

```
summon potion ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:swiftness",CustomPotionColor:16711680,CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:3b,Amplifier:5b,Duration:200},{Id:5b,Amplifier:5b,Duration:200}]}}}
```

This will summon a splash potion of swiftness, that also grants haste 5 and strength 5. `CustomPotionColor:16711680` changes the potions display color, and is formatted in decimal form.

I would recommend using [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.net) to generate potions, as NBT can get very complicated in potions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!